# dotnet MAUI Blazor App crashes only when deployed from iOS App store

Tags: blazor, maui, blazor-webassembly

I have built an app that works perfectly on Android and also on the iOS simulators.
However, whatever I try, when I release the ipa file through the apstore connect website & test flight, the app always crashes.

Two different behaviors, depending on the `<UseInterpreter>` element in the csproj file:

- When I use `<UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>`, the app not even starts, but immediately crashes with the error `"AppName" crashed.  Do you want to share additional information with the developer?`.
- When I use `<UseInterpreter>false</UseInterpreter>`, the app starts, but immediately crashes in the Blazor Web View, not showing any other than the White Screen and an indication that the app failed (with the Reload question).

Any one having a clue what could be causing it?  The strange thing is that debug on device works, deploying the `ipa` file fails, even if it's the same app.

Any suggestions, or ideas welcome.

**Relevant information**

- dotnet 7.0
- Publishing ipa, through command `dotnet publish -f:net7.0-ios -c:Release /p:IsPublishing=true`
- XCode 14.3
- Mac MT - Ventura 13.4

**The relevant source code in the csproj file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>My.ClientApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <EnableDefaultCssItems>false</EnableDefaultCssItems>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>Sfinx</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.xxxxx.xxxx</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>xxxxxxx-024C-41C1-8074-EF8DD528328C</ApplicationIdGuid>
        <ProvisioningType>automatic</ProvisioningType>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>3.33</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>57</ApplicationVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">24.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <Configurations>Debug;Release</Configurations>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
        <CodesignKey>iPhone Developer</CodesignKey>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
<!--        <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>-->
        <RuntimeIdentifier>iossimulator-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    </PropertyGroup>


    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
        <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
        <MtouchDebug>true</MtouchDebug>
        <CodesignEntitlements>Platforms\iOS\Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
        <CodesignKey>Apple Development:xxx</CodesignKey>
        <CodesignProvision>Automatic</CodesignProvision>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution: xxxxx</CodesignKey>
        <CodesignProvision>XXXX v1 provisioning</CodesignProvision>
        <CodesignEntitlements>Platforms\iOS\Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
        <ArchiveOnBuild>true</ArchiveOnBuild>
        <TcpPort>58181</TcpPort>
        <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink>
        <UseInterpreter>True</UseInterpreter>
    </PropertyGroup>
    

    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <RunAOTCompilation>false</RunAOTCompilation>
        <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
        <AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>
        <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
        <AndroidSigningKeyStore>myapp.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
        <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>key</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
        <AndroidSigningKeyPass>xxx</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
        <AndroidSigningStorePass>xxx</AndroidSigningStorePass>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
        <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </MauiIcon>

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\appsplash.svg" Color="#132040" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\App.Shared\App.Shared.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="5.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Flurl" Version="3.0.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="6.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.47.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="6.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.25.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="Interfaces\" />
        <None Remove="Services\Security\" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Interfaces" />
        <Folder Include="Interfaces\" />
        <Folder Include="Services\Security\" />
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\vendors\" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="appsettings.json" />
        <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
        <Content Remove="wwwroot\images\vendors\danalock\logo-square.png" />
        <Content Remove="wwwroot\images\vendors\nuki\logo-square.png" />
        <Content Remove="wwwroot\images\vendors\yale\logo-square.png" />
        <Content Remove="wwwroot\images\vendors\" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="appsettings.json" Condition="'$(ExcludeConfigFilesFromBuildOutput)'!='true'">
            <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </EmbeddedResource>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="appsettings.Development.json" Condition="'$(ExcludeConfigFilesFromBuildOutput)'!='true'">
            <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <BundleResource Include="wwwroot\images\vendors\danalock\logo-square.png">
            <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </BundleResource>
        <BundleResource Include="wwwroot\images\vendors\nuki\logo-square.png">
            <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </BundleResource>
        <BundleResource Include="wwwroot\images\vendors\yale\logo-square.png">
            <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </BundleResource>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: You mentioned the app works in Debug mode when deployed to a physical device. Does it work in release mode when deployed to a physical device?